# Problems using pointers with an dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am reading integers from an infile and adding them to an int array using pointers.

I have traced through the code multiple times and everything seems to flow logically and I am not getting any syntax errors or warnings in the compiler so I'm not sure what's wrong.

This program requires us to use arrays and not a vector or else I don't think I would be having these problems.

Now my output is reading all kinds of screwy. I know it has to do with the pointers but I am at a loss at the moment.

Infile:

```
3
456
593
94
58
8
5693
211
```

Output:

```
The items in the array are as follows.
7476376, 7475472, -17891602, 17891602, -17891602, -17891602, -17891602, -178916
```

collections.h

```
class collections
{
    public:
        collections();
        void add(int);  //adds the value to the array.
        void print();  //prints item of the array comma separated.
        ~collections();
    protected:
        int arraySize;
        int *array;
};
```

Constructor:

```
collections::collections()
{
    arraySize = 1;
    array = new int[arraySize];
}//done
```

void add:

```
void collections::add(int value) //adds the value to the array.
{
    //initial add to master array.
    if (arraySize == 1)
    {
        array[0] = value;
        arraySize++;
    }

    //every other add to master array.
    else
    {
        //temp array.
        int *tempArray = new int[(arraySize)];

        //copies old array into temp array.
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize-1; i++)
        {
            tempArray[i] = array[i];
        }

        //adds new incoming value to temp array.
        tempArray[(arraySize-1)] = value;

        //new master array
        delete [] array;
        int *array = new int[arraySize];

        //copies temp to master array.
        for (int j =0; j < arraySize; j++)
        {
            array[j] = tempArray[j];
        }

        //cleanup
        delete [] tempArray;
        arraySize ++;
    }
} //done
```

void print:

```
void collections::print() //prints item of the array comma separated.
{
   cout << "The items in the array are as follows.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << ", ";
    }
}//done
```

Sorry, I know this might be simple but for the life of me I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accidentally declared a local copy of `array` which overrides the class member:

```
//new master array
delete [] array;
int *array = new int[arraySize];
^^^^^
```

Remove the `int *` from that last line and the rest looks okay.

PS: Have you considered using `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: This did it. Thanks.

Teacher said not to use vectors on this.